# Am I able to add my copy of The Secret World to Origin?

Tags: origin, the-secret-world

I purchased The Secret World shortly after it came out via [The Secret World website](http://www.thesecretworld.com/). The Secret World is published by Electronic Arts and is available to purchase through Origin. Is it possible for me to be able to add the copy of The Secret World that I own to my Origin account?

I had a look in my The Secret World account to see if there was a CD Key or similar that I could add to Origin but all it states is "This account has a game key";

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, EA may be the publisher but (luckily!) it is not part of the Origin distribution system.

TheSecretWorld has its own, separate launcher and patcher.

The accounts for TSW are in the same system as Anarchy Onlinge, Age of Conan, Bloodline Champions and Pets vs Monsters.